# Blender 2D Animation - Background Image Won't Export

Tags: 2d

I imported a background image with a 2D animation, why isn't the background image rendered when I export?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Pleas e add more details about what you did, to help others to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

so I actually found the answer.  I'll copy and paste it.

"When dragging an image from a folder to the 2D-anim workspace, an empty with the image is created. This will never render, and is probably meant as an reference-image.

Use "images as planes" instead. If the menu-items are not there (that was my problem) then disable and re-enable the addon "images as planes"

Open userpreferences->addons

Find "images as planes"

Enable it

Menu-entries are now under "file->import" and "add->images""

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, because I was having the same problem and your answer really helped me out when I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Consider marking it as the preferred answer to make it easier for others to find.